# How to re initialize a char * variable in c

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I am writing a simple shell using c++. Here is my code. It will work normally for just one round, and stop working since the second round in that `while(1)` loop. I actually found out the reason for this, it is my `char *command` variable will keep growing. For example, the first round I type in ls, then my command is "ls". Then whatever I type in the second round will add to the ls, so if I type in ls again, then my command variable will be lsls. So it stops my shell working normally.  So i am wondering is there a way to re initialize my command or erase the contents of my command?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int i=0;
char c;
char *command;
while (1){
        cout<< "#?: -> ";
        while (( c = getchar()) != '\n'){
        command[i++] = c;}


        if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0){
                break;
        }
        if ( strcmp(command, "date")==0){
                system("date");
        }
        else if ( strcmp(command, "vim")==0){
                system("vim");
        }
        else if ( strcmp(command,"top")==0){
                system("top");
        }
        else if ( strcmp(command,"ps")==0){
                system("ps");
        }
        else if ( strcmp(command,"ls")==0){
                system("ls");
        }
         else if ( strcmp(command,"man")==0){
                system("man");
        }
        for (int j=0;j<100;j++){
        command[j]='/0';
        }
        cout<<command;

        //cin>>command;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `int i = 0;` initialization happens outside the loop. So, `i` is only ever incremented and it's never reset to 0, so yeah, your commands will be just appended one after another. Now think about what you have to do in order to correct this. Also, you never allocate any memory for `command`, so dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: This isn't going to work anyway. `command` is just pointing off somewhere into the void. I suggest you use an array.

Comment: Your title says C. Your text says C++. Your code looks like C, but you need a C++ compiler to compile it. Pick a language and stick with it. C and C++ are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 1):

Add `i=0;` at the beginning of your while loop

```
char *command= new char[100];
while (1){
        i=0;
        cout<< "#?: -> ";
        while (( c = getchar()) != '\n'){
        command[i++] = c;}
```

When you enter the second round, `i` has the value from the previous round, which is causing your bug. So just initialize `i` as zero inside your while loop. You are also not giving `command` an address due to which whatever you were trying just causes undefined behavior.

There is also an error here

```
command[j]='/0';
```

it should be

```
command[j]='\0';
```

Null character is `\0` and not `/0`.